# How many actuators does the F-35 have for each primary control surface?

Tags: flight-controls, control-surfaces, f-35

How many actuators does the F-35 have for each primary control surface like rudder, stabilator or aileron? And is it active/active or active/standby?

Answer (score 1):

Just one per control surface.  Though the airplane is unique with using a single Electro-Hydrostatic Actuator (EHA) per control surface as opposed to a centralized hydraulics system.

https://www.f35.com/in-depth/detail/up-in-the-air-understanding-the-f-35-air-vehicle

I don’t know what you mean by active/standby but the surface actuators are commanded by inputs from the flight control computers, which respond as needed to stick and rudder inputs from the pilot to achieve a desired aircraft reaction to a control input.

Comment: When there are two actuators per surface, active-active means that both are commanded and energized; if one malfunctions, you may have force fight. Active-standby means that only one is active at a time; if one malfunctions, the other one takes over while the first one is de-energized. The downside is there is a time lag between the takeover and your surface may run away during that time.